# phpmailer 5.2.23 redirect uri

Tags: php, phpmailer

[image: Google Error]

I have installed phpmailer 5.2.23
I am working on getting an auth token with this code from package list
I am setting the redirect uri to https://localhost:7764
in google i set the Authorized JavaScript origins to the following:
https://localhost:7764
https://{my ip }:7764
https://{my ip}
and also http
on the Authorized redirect URIs i have set the to 
https://localhost:7764
https://{my domain name}:7764
https://{my domain name}
and also http
I am getting mismatched uri
I have cleared the cache in the browser
any idea what im doing wrong?

```
$provider = new League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google([
'clientId'     => '{google-app-id}',
'clientSecret' => '{google-app-secret}',
'redirectUri'  => 'https://example.com/callback-url',
'hostedDomain' => 'https://example.com',
]);

if (!empty($_GET['error'])) {

// Got an error, probably user denied access
exit('Got error: ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET['error'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

} elseif (empty($_GET['code'])) {

// If we don't have an authorization code then get one
$authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl();
$_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $provider->getState();
header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
exit;

} elseif (empty($_GET['state']) || ($_GET['state'] !== $_SESSION['oauth2state'])) {

// State is invalid, possible CSRF attack in progress
unset($_SESSION['oauth2state']);
exit('Invalid state');

} else {

// Try to get an access token (using the authorization code grant)
$token = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
    'code' => $_GET['code']
]);

// Optional: Now you have a token you can look up a users profile data
try {

    // We got an access token, let's now get the owner details
    $ownerDetails = $provider->getResourceOwner($token);

    // Use these details to create a new profile
    printf('Hello %s!', $ownerDetails->getFirstName());

} catch (Exception $e) {

    // Failed to get user details
    exit('Something went wrong: ' . $e->getMessage());

}

// Use this to interact with an API on the users behalf
echo $token->getToken();

// Use this to get a new access token if the old one expires
echo $token->getRefreshToken();

// Number of seconds until the access token will expire, and need refreshing
echo $token->getExpires();
}
```

Comment: It's not clear where this error is coming from - you mention javascript, which isn't needed in this at all. Is this error coming from your browser, from PHP or where? You're also likely to have trouble getting google to call back a localhost URL. Also, I'd recommend trying the (as yet unreleased) [6.0 branch of PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/6.0) - the OAuth implementation is much better in there.

Comment: i added a screenshot of what i am seeing but i will try 6
How do i get it on composer? AND do i use the same oauth library as 5.2.23?

Comment: if you really use ``https://example.com/callback-url`` as redirectURI it can't work...